# Difference between nginx module and uWSGI plugin

Tags: nginx, uwsgi

I'm thinking about writing a REST adapter for MongoDB in C or C++. It would take a declarative config file and expose REST endpoints accordingly. It seems like there are two easy ways of doing this, as an [nginx module](http://www.evanmiller.org/nginx-modules-guide.html) in C or as a uWSGI plugin in C or C++.

Basically, I want to re-implement a project like [this](http://python-eve.org/) in C/C++.

Two [basic](https://github.com/simpl/ngx_mongo) [versions](https://github.com/minhajuddin/nginx-mongodb-rest) of this exist as nginx modules. uWSGI on the other hand would allow me to write it in C++ and use the hardened MongoDB C++ driver. (The MongoDB C driver is described as being "[in alpha](http://api.mongodb.org/c/current/)".)

I'm curious which is "more correct"/in-keeping with the design philosophy of nginx/uWSGI. Where in the `nginx -> uWSGI` server stack does this functionality belong? More generally I guess I'm a little confused as to why we need uWSGI at all or what role it provides above just nginx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be nginx-friendly a module must be non-blocking and must not use calls like fork().

If you can write a nginx module like this, use the nginx approach. The problem is that all of the current available nginx modules for mongodb are blocking (they generally use threadpools but can potentially blocks).

The only solution would be reimplementing the mongodb protocol (check this project http://mojolicio.us/perldoc/Mango) without using the currently available libraries.

On the other side uWSGI has not such limits (it can use processes, threads and coroutines), and a gridfs module is already available: http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/GridFS.html

The problem is that there is no doc about writing uwsgi plugins, so you have to base yourself on the current available ones

Btw, you need uWSGI behind nginx when you have something that cannot be made nginx-friendly (like CGI, or blocking web applications)

Comment: There is an nginx module that re-implements the BSON protocol and uses the nginx "upstream" callbacks,  see https://github.com/simpl/ngx_mongo/. An explanation of the callbacks is at http://www.evanmiller.org/nginx-modules-guide.html#proxying-summary. Thanks for the explanation, now I understand why they chose to structure it that way.